# Why would 'Embedding' be in an ActiveX EXE process description?

Tags: windows, vb6, activex, windows-server-2012-r2

We are having some strange issues on Windows Server 2012 (both normal and R2). Every once in a while (seemingly randomly) we start getting strange errors with all the programs on a server (API calls to Process32Next fail for instance). These occurrences seem to be a associated with one or more of our old ActiveX EXE (VB6) programs suddenly showing 'Embedding' in their description in the process viewer (task manager or Process Hacker). The problem goes away when everyone logs off. I cannot find anything much on Google about this. These programs have been around unchanged for over a decade and I cannot see how ANY program could affect every other program on a server but I am hoping that understanding why the Embedding description shows up might help lead to a solution.

Also, sometimes the name of the process is blank as well.

Comment: Hello good morning! Did you have your problem solved? We're currently experiencing the same issue and can't solve it.

Comment: Hello again! Could you please give me some tips of what you've done? We are recurrently experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX EXE is another name for Automation Server.  This is one of several technologies built on top of COM that fall into the OLE 1.0, OLE 2.0, and OLE custom control (a.k.a. ActiveX) categories.  OLE stands for Object Linking and Embedding.

My guess is that wherever you are looking this term "Embedding" is being used to indicate an Automation Server.  So it probably has no direct bearing on your issues.

I suspect this is a case of "looking where the light is good."

You may be running into some issues related to Session 0 Isolation, User Interface Privilege Isolation, or both.  Or more likely you might have DCOM/Automation activation settings incorrect for one or more of these programs.

You might start by looking at the definitions for these servers in DCOMCNFG.EXE.  People often rely on defaults and that may not be what you should have.  Some of these might be defined in COM+ which means additional rules.  Some of these interact with user rights and group membership.

But we have far too little specific information to really be of much help here.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will tell this to our Network person. We do have many users connecting using remote terminals.

Comment: Embedding and Automation switches means COM is starting the program because some program is asking it to. Try in a command prompt `wmic process get name,processid,parentprocessid,commandline /format:list` to see what app is starting it.

Comment: I read this but was not able to verify it. I created a reference to the EXE using CoCreateInstance and the Embedding string did not appear. I Will try your suggestion though, thank you.

Comment: it's either `/embedding` or `/a`.